# XMLPullParser not reading empty tags like <hours/>

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

Below is my XML, I am going to parse it using XMLPullParser. The parser correctly reads values from tags like

```
<hours>Monday: 1:00 PM - 3:00 PM Thursday: 8:30 AM - 12:30 PM</hours>
```

But if there is no timing data given by the webservice, the hours tag is empty:

```
<hours/>
```

and XMLPullParser skips those tags. I want to read a null value or empty string from such tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <city_data>
    <city_details>
      <id>1</id>
      <city>City1</city>
      <location>5390 Park</location>
      <phoneno>239-963</phoneno>
      <fax>239-963</fax>
      <hours>Monday: 1:00 PM - 3:00 PM Thursday: 8:30 AM - 12:30 PM</hours>
      <latitude>26.2134964</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.7672781</longitude>
      <action>2</action>
    </city_details>
  </city_data>
  <city_data>
    <city_details>
      <id>2</id>
      <city>City2</city>
      <location>13100 Westlinks</location>
      <phoneno>239</phoneno>
      <fax>239-332</fax>
      <hours/>
      <latitude>26.553446</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.7560699</longitude>
      <action>2</action>
    </city_details>
  </city_data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `XmlPullParser.isEmptyElementTag()` to detect empty tags like <hours/>. This will allow you to handle

> <hours>Monday: 1:00 PM - 3:00 PM Thursday: 8:30 AM - 12:30
>   PM</hours>

differently than

> <hours/>.

The documentation is here: [XmlPullParser.isEmptyElementTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#isEmptyElementTag())